# show form @postMapping EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
@Controller
    public static class forLostController {

        @GetMapping("/losing")
        public String lostingForm(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("losing", new lostUser());
            return "losing";
        }

        @PostMapping("/losing")
        public String losingSubmit(@ModelAttribute lostUser losing) throws BrokerException {
            //it works!!
            System.out.println(losing.getName());
            System.out.println(losing.getHeight());
            
            //something wrong while showing the page "resultForLost.html" 
            return "resultForLost";
        }

    }
```

resultForLost.html:

```
<span class="visible-xs"><p th:text="'姓名: ' + ${losing.name}" /></span>
```

In the console of the Idea:

```
2020-10-13 21:30:54.485 ERROR 7941 --- [nio-9998-exec-3] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-9998-exec-3] Exception processing template "resultForLost": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "losing.name" (template: "resultForLost" - line 30, col 52)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "losing.name" (template: "resultForLost" - line 30, col 52)

...

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null

...

2020-10-13 21:30:54.486 ERROR 7941 --- [nio-9998-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "losing.name" (template: "resultForLost" - line 30, col 52)] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

Why it is null for losing? The input of the function `losingSubmit()` is `@ModelAttribute lostUser losing`, so it will be sent to the "resultForLost.html" page, right?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully run it without error.

```
@PostMapping("/finding")
        public String losingSubmit(@ModelAttribute("losing") lostUser losing) throws BrokerException {
    //code
}
```

it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `losing` attribute to the model in `losingSubmit` method.

```
 @PostMapping("/losing")
        public String losingSubmit(@ModelAttribute lostUser losing, Model model) throws BrokerException {
            //it works!!
            System.out.println(losing.getName());
            System.out.println(losing.getHeight());
            
            //add this line
            model.addAttribute("losing", losing); 
            
            //something wrong while showing the page "resultForLost.html" 
            return "resultForLost";
        }
```

Comment: Is the "model" the input of the function? I don’t know how “model” was passed in

Comment: Yeah right, sorry I forgot to include that. Editing the answer.